# Android 4+ decreased thread cpu time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app a have some very expensive computations in background Thread written in Java. On Andrdoid 2.3 (800MHz single core) it work fast enough, but on Android 4+(1.5GHz quad core) it becomes terribly slow. Also in profiler it takes the same CPU time, ase before. As i understand it happens because of decreased background thread priority.

```
getThreadGroup().setMaxPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Has no effect.

Trace for Android 2.3. Real time ~10sec. Thread-108
[image: Trace for Android 2.3. Real time ~10sec. Thread-108]
Trace for Android 4.4. Real time ~45sec. Thread-1762
[image: Trace for Android 4.4. Real time ~45sec. Thread-1762]

Can i increase thread cpu-time priority ?